# Grow container to the size (height) of the UILabel [ios]

Tags: ios, swift

Lets say I have a container (UIView) which has just 1 child (UILabel) in it.

Is it possible to have the container auto size (height) to the height of the UILabel. As the content of the UILabel is set dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
func rectForText(text: String, font: UIFont, maxSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let attrString = NSAttributedString.init(string: text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font])
    let rect = attrString.boundingRectWithSize(maxSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
    let size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)
    return size
}

let labelSize = rectForText("your text here", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(your font), maxSize: CGSizeMake(your label width,999))
let labelHeight = labelSize.height
```

assign `labelHeight` to your `UIView's` height.